# Kubectl diff whole directory, but to exclude non-yaml files?

Tags: kubectl

With the following command, I can check differences recursively within one directory.

```
k diff -R -f .
```

But if that dir contains non-yaml files, command will break.

For example, if there are some json files within dir I will get: `error: unable to decode "test.json": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"type":...`

Is there an elegant solution to tell kubectl to execute diff only against yaml files...?

Comment: can you give an example of non-yaml file so we can try reproducing the issue ?

Comment: It's not reproducible to be, when I have a yaml and a non-yaml(binary file) present in the same directory. the command is working fine. So perhaps, you add  a sample file in the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've edited my question. Any json file could be an example. I'm not sure what you think when you say "binary file" @P.... ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with a json file, Ididn't tried it before.  Try this `k diff -R -f "*.yaml" -f "*.yml"`

Comment: doesn't work: `the path "*.yaml" does not exist`

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.